# fazer quebra de linha automática com dados do banco

Tags: jquery, html, css, css3

Olá, tenho uma `ul` com `li's` que recebem nomes de produtos.
Acontece que quando eu altero a resolução para mobile, por exemplo `320px`, então se o nome do produto for grande, logo não caberá dentro da li que terá os `320px`;

Nesse caso, como não dá para `prever o tamanho de cada nome de produto` que chega no banco, será que existe uma forma do texto (nome do produto) fazer quebra de `linha automática`?

Por exemplo: o nome

`Manual, P212, 1 bandejas de 120cm x 70cm e prensagem de 200kg`.

Em uma resolução acima de 860px, cabe tranaquilo, mas abaixo disso será necessário fazer por exemplo:

```
Manual, P212, 1 bandejas de 120cm x 70cm
e prensagem de 200kg
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer por meio de CSS, usando `@media` para resoluções abaixo de 860px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
    .suaClasse{
        word-break: break-all;
    }
}
```